# Got an strange behavior for nullable integer type validation message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Got an strange behaviour and could find why this is happening.
Imagine you have null-able integer type property on your model and you want to add validation message that particular property only accept integer values. 
Plus if you add editorfor on cshtmml, that particular property validation message not showing but if you add text box for it work fine any idea?
See my code in below

Model

```
[DisplayName( "Property Name" )]
[Range( 0, 50 )]
[Integer( ErrorMessage = "Specify this property using numbers only" )]
public int? NumberofProperty { get; set; }
```

CSHTML NOT showing error message

```
<div class="editor-label">
 @Html.LabelFor( model => model.NumberofProperty )
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor ( model => model.NumberofProperty )
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.NumberofProperty )
</div>
```

CSHTML that showing error message

```
 <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor( model => model.NumberofProperty )
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.NumberofProperty , new { style= "width:50px"} )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.NumberofProperty )
</div>
```

any idea why is this behavior
cheers

Comment: "working" and "Not working" are useless without some context. What makes them "not work"? If you don't have an editor template setup for nullable int's then of course that won't work as expected..

Comment: Hi Simon can you specify what you mean?

Comment: Can _you_ specify what _you_ mean? Your question doesn't make sense (to me anyway).

Comment: big pardon. I have edited my question does it make any sense now?

Comment: Do you have an EditorTemplate setup for `Nullable<int>`?

Comment: No I don't and also why do i need that.?....
also let me know why the EditorFor not showing the error message and why TextBoxFor showing the error message.

Comment: `EditorFor` will just call `TextBox(...)` not `TextBoxFor` (IIRC). Without `TextBoxFor`.. your model attributes won't be taken into account. So you need to setup an EditorTemplate that calls `TextBoxFor` instead of the default `TextBox`.

Comment: can you post any link or example regarding this. also do not forgot put it as answer.

Comment: A simple Google brings up articles such as: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/672591/Exploring-Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Thanks Simon yes I got this , again thanks for point me to right path

Comment: Hi Simon quick thing What is IIRC?

Comment: "If I recall correctly".